# Using Views in couchDB

Tags: couchdb

Can you "pass" a "parameter" to a view's map function from the query part of a URL? If so, could you show me an example? By, parameter I mean anyway you can access parts of the query string within the map or reduce function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not quite how views works.  The view nominates key-value pairs, where the value could be the whole document.  You then ask for something where the key is exactly some value or between a range of values.  You have to bend your mind around this way of thinking or it won't make sense.  The view is independent of parameters, and then it is narrowed down based on the key or startKey/endKey parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure I need to wrap my mind around it. but I do appreciate your answer. Saves me from looking around forever.